# Is there a way to see all favorite questions of all my communities?

Tags: support, stackexchange, community, bookmarks

So, since as a programmer I use many different stackexchange sites, like

- Stack Overflow
- Software Engineering
- Game Development
- Theoretical Computer Science

I want to see all questions that I have favorited to come back to, rather than having to go to my profile on all of those sites and checking, wheter the specific thread that I am looking for, is on there.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can log in at [the Stack Exchange website](https://stackexchange.com/). If you visit your profile there, you'll see activities across the network. There's a "favorites" tab that shows you your favorite questions from across the network.